# Is that kind of structure allowed in XML?

Tags: xml

Is that kind of structure allowed in XML ?

```
<category>
    <pattern>ANSWER MY QUESTION</pattern>
    <template>
        Please try asking 
        <set name="it">your question</set> 
        another way.
    </template>   
</category>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly valid. In XML Schema parlance, it's known as the ["mixed content" model](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch07_05.htm).

Whether or not it's a good idea, however, is another question entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't it be? XML can be anything you as long as it's properly formatted, and that looks properly formatted as far as I'm concerned.